# Текстовый(code) редактор в Android

Tags: android, javascript, php

Доброго времени суток. Я занимаюсь разработкой веб-интерфейсов на ExtJs4 & php.
Периодически совершаю длительные поездки, в связи с чем приобрел себе планшет на ос Android 2.3; сейчас в поездках читаю.
Иногда в голову приходят мысли, которые в тот момент кажутся умными. Записываю их, если выходит, на бумагу.
Но вот возник вопрос: может кто подскажет приложение, по типу блокнота?) вообще было бы очень не плохо, если бы с подсветкой синтаксиса, но это уже второстепенное.
По маркету пробежался, на первый взгляд ничего такого не нашел.

Суть: нужно приложение для Android, по типу блокнота. Должен открывать файлы форматов *.js,* .php, *.sql,* .log как текстовые. Приятным дополнением было бы - подсветка синтаксиса.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего вам [сюда](https://market.android.com/search?q=code+editor&c=apps)

Из представленного, подходят, [данный](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hoodwebmedia.hello&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5ob29kd2VibWVkaWEuaGVsbG8iXQ..), еще [вот](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.welant.webmaster.DEMO&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS53ZWxhbnQud2VibWFzdGVyLkRFTU8iXQ..) и [вот](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aor.droidedit&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5hb3IuZHJvaWRlZGl0Il0.). Так же есть и платные версии.

Нашел [вот такой viewer](https://market.android.com/details?id=twig.nguyen.codepeeker&feature=also_installed#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwNCwidHdpZy5uZ3V5ZW4uY29kZXBlZWtlciJd), в списке поддерживаемых языков, но скорее всего не умеет редактировать текст:

- ActionScript 3 (as3)
- Terminal scripts (bash, shell, sh)
- C/C++ (c, cc, cpp, h, hpp)
- C# (c-sharp, csharp, cs)
- CSS
- Delphi/Pascal
- Diff/patch files
- Groovy
- Java
- JavaFX (jfx)
- **JavaScript (js, jscript)**
- Perl (pl)
- **PHP**
- Text (txt)
- PowerShell (ps)
- Python (py)
- Ruby (rails, ror)
- Scala
- **SQL**
- Visual Basics (vb, vbnet)
- Verilog & System Verilog (v, sv)
- XML (xml, xaml, xslt, html, xhtml)

Comment: Благодарю :)
дома буду - потестю.
Причина такого глупого вопроса: я чуть чуть отстал от жизни, и это первый мой touch инструмент... естественно и с андроидом не знаком.

Comment: Согласен..